# Android - detect device max OpenGL Version

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have app, that uses OpenGL ES 2 or 3. If 3 is available, it should be preferred, because I am using some of its functionality to improve performance.
Is there a way, how to detect ES version before calling

```
setEGLContextClientVersion
```

In manifest, I have

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

On devices, that supportes only 2.0 I want init GL with 2.0. But if device support both - 2.0 and 3.0 (or 3.1) I want to use the later.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Google Source [[Compatibility Test Suite]](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/f1b6c7d504ae31f3500ce5c9b2e75dadb2799f4d/tests/tests/opengl/src/android/opengl/cts/OpenGlEsVersionTest.java):

```
private static int getVersionFromActivityManager(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager =
            (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConfigurationInfo configInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        if (configInfo.reqGlEsVersion != ConfigurationInfo.GL_ES_VERSION_UNDEFINED) {
            return configInfo.reqGlEsVersion;
        } else {
            return 1 << 16; // Lack of property means OpenGL ES version 1
        }
    }




    private static int getVersionFromPackageManager(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        FeatureInfo[] featureInfos = packageManager.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
        if (featureInfos != null && featureInfos.length > 0) {
            for (FeatureInfo featureInfo : featureInfos) {
                // Null feature name means this feature is the open gl es version feature.
                if (featureInfo.name == null) {
                    if (featureInfo.reqGlEsVersion != FeatureInfo.GL_ES_VERSION_UNDEFINED) {
                        return featureInfo.reqGlEsVersion;
                    } else {
                        return 1 << 16; // Lack of property means OpenGL ES version 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure Shaman's approach is fine, but Google's docs do seem to recommend two other approaches. From here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

> Before using OpenGL ES features from a version higher than the minimum required in your application manifest, your application should check the version of the API available on the device. You can do this in one of two ways:
>
> Attempt to create the higher-level OpenGL ES context (EGLContext) and
>   check the result.
>
> Create a minimum-supported OpenGL ES context and check the version
>   value.
>
> The following example code demonstrates how to check the available
>   OpenGL ES version by creating an EGLContext and checking the result.
>   This example shows how to check for OpenGL ES 3.0 version:

```
private static double glVersion = 3.0;

private static class ContextFactory implements GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory {

  private static int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;

  public EGLContext createContext(
          EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {

      Log.w(TAG, "creating OpenGL ES " + glVersion + " context");
      int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, (int) glVersion,
              EGL10.EGL_NONE };
      // attempt to create a OpenGL ES 3.0 context
      EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(
              display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
      return context; // returns null if 3.0 is not supported;
  }
}
```

> If the createContext() method show above returns null, your code
>   should create a OpenGL ES 2.0 context instead and fall back to using
>   only that API.
>
> The following code example demonstrates how to check the OpenGL ES
>   version by creating a minimum supported context first, and then
>   checking the version string:

```
// Create a minimum supported OpenGL ES context, then check:
String version = javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10.glGetString(
        GL10.GL_VERSION);
Log.w(TAG, "Version: " + version );
// The version format is displayed as: "OpenGL ES <major>.<minor>"
// followed by optional content provided by the implementation.
```

> With this approach, if you discover that the device supports a
>   higher-level API version, you must destroy the minimum OpenGL ES
>   context and create a new context with the higher available API
>   version.